# Server Side Include

Tags: html, text-files, ssi

Is it possible to use a server side include to access files that are outside of the server?

If not what are some other options to do this?

Comment: I am trying to access information from a txt file that would be located outside the folder in a drive, for people to be able to upload info onto that file, and it could show up on the website, without the site having to be published

Comment: wow, I did not hear about SSI since a looooong time...

Answer (score 3):

Use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) to get data outside of the domain. If you want to then execute the data you receive, go ahead and `eval()` it. But, be forewarned that this will get the 'output' of the page. Meaning if it is an executed page like a '.php' page, you will get the data that comes out as a result of it being processed.

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The same is true for [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents), and [`fopen()`](https://www.php.net/fopen)

If you wanted to grab the 'actual' contents of the file, you would want to set up a proxy of sorts on the other server. (You can't do it on your server because then it would be a security flaw in how server-side-scripting works).

```
<?php

// Read the requested file out
readfile($_GET['file']);
```

That will give you the contents of any file you request:

`http://test.com/handler.php?file=handler.php`

But, if anyone else finds it, it could be dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention the server software but I'll assume Apache, where SSI is provided by the [mod_include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_include.html) module. The *include* element does not allow remote files. However, you have *exec*, which allows to execute any external tool; you can use it to call *wget* or any other command of your choice.

However, it might not be so complicate. If you can mount the remote directory in the local system, you can create a plain symlink and use a regular *include*.

Or, as already suggested, PHP is really simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like file_get_contents() or fopen() to do this in php, e.g.

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/include');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nginx's server side includes can use any full url eg:

```
<!--# include virtual="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" -->
```