# Modern JS method of PHP 'include' function

Tags: javascript, php, html, frameworks, include

With the ever-growing library of JS frameworks (since I last build a website ~ 2014) is there a simple JS replacement/alternative for PHP's 'include' function. Or is PHP include still a relevant method of including chunks of code?

I'm building a website and want to achieve some basics like 'including' footers, headers, menu's etc. but would rather not make all my pages .php - it feels a bit clunky and unnecessary.

I found a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326742/server-side-includes-alternative) referencing Jekyll but it was a bit more specific to GitHub. Any pointers in the right direction appreciated!

Comment: `include` is still the method for including other files in a php file. There's no alternative for that.

Comment: Packaging your javascript is the best option here, comes with other advantages like tree-shaking, es6 trans-piling etc..  Have a look at webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my first answer wasn't covering the interested question I decided to fully edit and replace the answer. Here we go..

**Solutions**

1 - JQuery load() function

```
<!-- LOAD JQUERY -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<!-- "INCLUDE" external files with code -->
<script> 
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
</script>
```

2 - NPM gulp package which lets you includes file and pass some parameters/values

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  @@include('./header.html')
  @@include('./main.html')
  </body>
</html>
```

an example of a gulp task:

```
var fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
    gulp = require('gulp');

    gulp.task('html', function() {
        return gulp.src(['./src/html/views/*.html'])
            .pipe(fileInclude({
                prefix: '@@',
                basepath: 'src/html'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
    });
```

3 - pure javascript via document.write function and including script with it via src

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="header.js"></script>
```

4 - pure ajax request that requests additional data and places it where it should be placed on the page

5 - SSI (Server Side Include), as I mentioned it in comment

6 - iframes (not the best way, though)

7 - asp/jsp server script include (as alternative to php server script include)

More info here:

[Common Header / Footer with static HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418503/common-header-footer-with-static-html)

[Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages)

Hopefully you can find the best way that will suit your needs from one of this.

Comment: upvote for spending time and showing some passion! Thanks for sharing your thoughts, I probably need something a bit more concrete as my sole requirement here is for an include alternative in JS, the website will be simple in terms of backend requirements!

Comment: Thank you and sorry for improperly understanding of your goal! I was mainly focused on "php" and " frameworks" words combo in comparison to "javascript alternative" and totally forgot about include function..

As for about your goal - have you thought about SSI (old) style of including? Example: `<!--#include file="content.html"-->`. Some people still prefer it. It has a lot of advantages, like no-need to load jquery for other popular include alternative, but some requirements too.

Here's detailed explanation and comparison to ajax-method: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/103838

Comment: Here's another opinion on prefering SSI over ajax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29858653/8670275