# Header and footer file in every HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, github-pages

I'm creating a website using GitHub Pages and I want to put the header and footer into separate documents to then link to them on each page I make. GitHub pages only supports static websites, so I can't use PHP or anything like that.
I'm trying to use the advice I found on:

[Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDFxEALe0JA&ab_channel=JoseMartinez

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-include-a-header-and-footer-file-in-every-HTML-page-we-are-designing

which uses jQuery but it's just not working for me. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

My file hierarchy:

```
- index.html
- html
    - header.html
    - footer.html
    - otherfiles.html
- css
    - header.css
    - footer.css
    - otherfiles.css
```

this is in the index.html file:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function() {
  $("#header").load("html/header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("html/footer.html"); 
});
</script>


</head>

<body>

<!-- Header-->
<div id="header"></div>
 
<!--main section-->

<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer"></div>
```

And I put this in footer.html and header.html body:

```html
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com">click here for google</a>
```

This is from what I can tell, what I'm meant to do, but it's not working at all. Just no header or footer appears on my website.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22326742/519413. I won't VTC as this may be an outdated answer now

Comment: That post looks like a general inquiry. I'm wanting a solution to the jQuery code. I'm not sure how to use Jekyll but it looks like I have to build an entire website with it? Not sure how to convert my website to a Jekyll website, and it seems like a lot when I already have a website and all I want to do is add the same footer to every page. I might just end up copy pasting it, I've been trying to find a solution for days I feel like I'm going insane

Answer (score -1):

possibly look into using an iframe object to reference the page, theres an example on the last link you posted (one of the comments)

**OR** try removing header/footer files from the html folder and put them in the same directory as index.html, to eliminate the possibility that its the file reference that is the issue.

**OR** look into using the handlebars.js library.  this library can be used to implement an MVC layout (basically files are referenced by a home controller to display content).  And it will work with GithubPages, I've done it before.

hopefully this helps a little, at the very least pointing you in the right direction.